# How to create an extension for VS Studio 2022 for mac?

Tags: monodevelop, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I have VS 2022 for Mac, latest released version **17.3.5**.

I do not have the "IDE Extension" template:
[image]

I do have the AddinMaker plugin:
[image]

I do not have the Xamarin support installed in VS Mac 2022, do I need it to create extensions?

Comment: VS for Mac is evolving fast to get rid of the MonoDevelop legacies, so at this moment it is not clearly how you are supposed to write extensions for it. Contact Microsoft support directly if you have an active contract, or post through its feedback site https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=41&stateGroup=active

Comment: There is some information on the developer community about how to use addin maker, even though the project templates are currently not available, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Extensions-support-for-Vis/10060096#T-N10060705

Comment: @MattWard That worked, but I had to use MonoDevelo.Core 17.3 instead of 17.0, (hope this helps anyone reading this). Thanks!!!

Comment: Do not really see how VS for Mac is evolving fast as it is degrading slowly looking like a soon-to-be-discontinued product. Try to search and replace text inside selection and you'll switch to VS for Windows upon failing.